# Alternative to using -1 for invalid value

Tags: coding-style

I was reading the coding standards for insomniac games here: http://www.insomniacgames.com/core-coding-standard/#id.8a4ef3275bfd and it mentions to not use "magic values". I'm not talking about magic numbers replaced with a named constant though.

In other words, don't use -1 to mean "invalid" or "not set". But it doesn't tell you what a better practice is. What do you guys do? How can you trust that the valid is actually valid without checking it? The only thing I could think of, would to have a bool that indicates it's valid or invalid, but this seems sloppy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if you read the next paragraph, they *do* tell you what they regard as better practice:

> “For things with discrete enumerated values, like ids, having a sentinel for "invalid" is okay, but keep make it an explicit constant. For example, the are encoding of DYN_JOINT_ID_INVALID (0xffffffff) in the old dynamic joint code is an appropriate use of sentinel values.”

Depending on the circumstances, it's arguable whether returning a unique error code, as they prefer, is preferable to returning a negative value, which is a well-established idiom. Exceptions, which they don't even mention, might be a better alternative. But what might be the best choice in theory is pretty well irrelevant: they've already made the decision, presumably for good reason, and put it in their coding standard, which you just have to live with.

Comment: oh. okay. I guess I'm retarded. Earlier in the standards doc they mention that they don't use exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: I think my confusion was that I didn't think to set a variable to a named magic number to indicate an invalid value. I normally just use them in code to replace a literal for ease of use and readability.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think it's a particularly well-thought-out or well-written coding standard (the paragraph I excerpted hasn't even been well proof-read). Using -1 as an error return for functions that normally return a non-negative integer is such a well-established idiom that it gets a pass from the “no magic numbers” rule in my book. There *can be* good technical reasons for a preference, but in this case it seems like an arbitrary preference of theirs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `enum` to return a better value that makes more sense. `enums` really just give numbers names.

```
enum Errors {
    NO_DATA_RECIEVED
    COMPUTER_ON_FIRE
    WIFI_OFF
}
```

You would use it like:

```
throw COMPUTER_ON_FIRE;
```

And in the error handler:

```
if(error == COMPUTER_ON_FIRE)
     displayDialog("Grab a fire extinguisher!");
```

This is a lot more informative to the programmer than `return -1`- now you know what the problem actually is.

Comment: I'm thinking like an index into an array. -1 would mean, "not set". Using an enum, I don't think, would work in that case. I guess I could set an enum to have a value of -1...

Comment: Sure it would. If the enum is null, it was never processed or set. You could check the enum in a try block, or test for nullness before ever checking it, whichever works better.

Comment: You're missing commas inside your `enum` and you have made no provision for what happens when the function succeeds: the choices of return value all indicate errors. There's also no indication of how such a function, always returning a success/failure indicator, should or would communicate any value that it has computed to its caller.

Comment: @Emmet On your first point- it's psudeocode, so that really doesn't matter. However, on your second point, agreed. It should `throw` the error, not `return` it. I edited the answer.

Comment: I wasn't really concerned with this in the context of a return value. I was most concerned with respect to a member variable that needed to be used that wasn't set to something valid. I do see the point though.